# require not ip or deny from with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, country

So to prevent certain countries from visiting a website, I have to copy and paste the code of the countries to the .htaccess files.

But I see a couple of patterns.

It is "require not ip xx.xxx.xxx.xx/xx" and "deny from xx.xxx.xxx.xx/xx"

How are these different and which one works better?